# PhP form not receiving inputs

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I created a contact form contact.php , it submits values to send_contact.php & process the inputs

But whats happening is ,after I hit submit button , send_contact.php file is getting displayed in the browser

contact.php

```
  <table width="300" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form target="_blank" name="form1" method="post" action="send_contact.php" id="form1">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
              <td width="16%">Subject</td>

              <td width="2%">:</td>

              <td width="82%"><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="30" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Detail</td>

              <td>:</td>

              <td>
              <textarea name="detail" cols="24" rows="4" id="detail">
              </textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>

              <td>:</td>

              <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Email</td>

              <td>:</td>

              <td><input name="customer_mail" type="text" id="customer_mail" size="30" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td></td>

              <td></td>

              <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /><input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

send_contact.php

```
<?php

    // Contact subject
    $subject ="$subject"; 

    // Details
    $message="$detail";

    // Mail of sender
    $mail_from="$customer_mail"; 

    // From 
    $header="from: $name <$mail_from>";

    // Enter your email address
    $to ='abcd@gmail.com';
    $send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

    // Check, if message sent to your email 
    // display message "We've recived your information"
    if($send_contact){
    echo "We've recived your contact information";
    }
    else {
    echo "ERROR";
    }

?>
```

Comment: use php opening and closing tag "<?php ?>", if you have used short tag, it may not be supported on your server.

Comment: Is this full code of your send_contact.php as I don't see opening php tag(<?php). Also make sure you don't use the short tag(<?) as your server configuration might not be allowing this.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be depending on [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php), which is a dangerous PHP feature that has been entirely removed from recent versions of the language.

In order to access the data submitted from a form with `method="post"` you need to use [the `$_POST` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) array.

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the value from $_POST, for example

```
$subject ="$subject";
```

should be this:

```
$subject =$_POST['subject'];
```

This is the way you access values from forms with superglobal array $_POST